# why php ziparchive's extractTo method creates one-depth-level, instead folders tree? (folders names are cyrillic)

Tags: php, php-ziparchive, cyrillic

I Working with web server that works on unix.

I have zip archive which contains some folders tree:

```
section1
**subsection1-1
**subsection2-2

section2
**subsection2-1
```

All section's names are on `cyrillic`.

When i try to extract this archive by using `$zip->extractTo(...)`, i get only one depth level of sections.

```
section1
subsection1-1
subsection1-2
section2
subsection2-1
```

(same situation with nested files. they appears at the root level instead parent level)

Comment: Looking at the docs page for that method, this seems to be known behaviour. See [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php#116353) from 5 years ago for a possible workaround - I haven't tested it so can't vouch for it's efficacy or efficiency but it might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed.
The reason was: that my zip archive with folders was created by php's ziparchive on windows server. 
And when it was created - the local names of files and folders was with "\" separator. 
And i tried to export it on unix's server;

I fixed code of creating zip, by replacing "\" to "/" and it works fine now.